# Recovering Network Adapter Settings with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, window, wmi

I have a need to capture the original state/settings of network adapters in windows utilizing C#.  My project requires that we make specific changes to IP/Gateway,etc. to a network adapter and then later, revert the settings to its original settings. I have been using the `System.Management.ManagementObject` class to pull these needed properties, but I find that when a network adapter is disabled/disconnected, I am unable to pull statically set properties (IE:IP Address,Subnet Mask,Default gateway, Preferred/Alternate DNS Settings) on the adapter UNLESS it has a connection (regardless if it is enabled/disabled).

Digging through some registry settings, I can find where I believe these settings are set, but I am unable to make a correlation from the properties on the ManagementObject and entries in the registry.

**What I need to know is:**

- How to get properties set on disabled/disconnected network adapter configurations in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to do this is to query the driver and the driver for
the disabled NIC is not loaded.

When a network interface is disabled, the adapter's driver is unloaded. Without a loaded driver, Windows cannot request an address.

Consider the disabled device as not existing at all.

Comment: I think the issue I have is that I may enable a disabled device and then want to re-enable it.  If use netsh or just right clicking on the network adapter, i can see settings for the adapters, even if they are disabled.  That is the real information that I am trying to gather, because  I want my code to clean up after itself after the process is run